# Unable to connect to XAMPP MySQL from Netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, xampp

I am a windows 7 user and I'm having an issue with MySQL and XAMPP.

I use the MySQL that comes with XAMPP. I have changed the root password of MySQL using XAMPP's security page. Then I tried to connect to the MySQL server via Netbeans.

To try to connect I clicked on MySQL server option in the database drop down of the services pane, I gave it some settings:

```
server host name:localhost
username:root
port:3306
password:(my sql password)
path to admin module:(http:'//')localhost/phpmyadmin
sql start path:D:\D-drive\xampp-portable\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe(also tried mysql_start.bat)
sql stop path:</b>D:\D-drive\xampp-portable\mysql\bin\mysqladmin.exe(also tried sql_stop.bat)
```

Then I right click on MySQL server at localhost [root] and select Connect, this is when I get an error:

```
Unable to connect to the MySQL server:
org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseException: org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server..
The server may not be running or your MySQL connection properties may not be set correctly.  Do you want to edit your MySQL connection properties?
```

Changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 doesn't work either. I have the jdbc driver as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix that worked for me is as follows:

Please see that netbeans is an *allowed program* in your firewall as well as antivirus software
**to check:**

if netbeans startup page says "cannot connect to internet" then you must change your firewall and/or antivirus settings to allow it